# How can insert scrollbar to listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a Fragment layout that have also a `ListView`. I populate, this `ListView` with custom `ArrayAdapter`. Now, if I insert more items, I can't scrolling this list.

So I want to know how can I insert a vertical scrollbar to ListView.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="830dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutDate">

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

        <!--LIST OF AGENT-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutAgent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/layoutDate">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelListAgent"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/agent"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listOfAgent"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            </ListView>



        </LinearLayout>



        <TextView android:id="@+id/labelAgent"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:hint="Insert agent"
            android:clickable="true"
           />



    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the xml of your ListView:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Just checked your code. I think your problem could because you gave a fixed hight to your listview. Change `android:layout_height="120dp"` to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: I have try to write wrap_content instead of 120dp but the problem, is the same

Comment: Is there any particular reason for the ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

there is a scroollbar on listView by default.
you should set the height as android:layout_height="wrap_content" and remove the android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"

Comment: I have also remove this tag, but the problem, is the same :(

Comment: Try the new xml layout below, i think your xml layout might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

            <!--LIST OF AGENT-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutAgent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelListAgent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingStart="15dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="agent"/>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listOfAgent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5">
                </ListView>



            </LinearLayout>



            <TextView android:id="@+id/labelAgent"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:hint="Insert agent"
                android:clickable="true"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

When in the main activity, there is a ScrollView, the other Scrollar do not works. Then the solution is to remove ScrollView in top of my Layout file, and the ListView scrollbar, works